# css grid - getting grid to down rather than across across five equal columns

Tags: css

I am working in Aurelia and have a css file where I've set the css for this.

I am trying to build a week calendar layout where I have hour cells broken into sets of 4 (quarter hour) and populate down the page. For example say I had 45 divs that equate to 8 cells down and 5 across.

instead I have this:
[image]

It just flows down one column and fails to go to the next..

What I have is as follows:

```
<div class="cal-container">
    <div>
        <div class="au-target cal-today cal-border-right cal-quarter-hour" au-target-id="32"></div>
        <div class="au-target cal-today cal-border-right cal-half-hour" au-target-id="32"></div>
       <div class="au-target cal-today cal-border-right cal-quarter-hour" au-target-id="32"></div>
       <div class="au-target cal-today cal-border-right cal-hour" au-target-id="32"></div>.......
```

I wanted the css to force the flow down the column first reach an end and then procceed down the next column and so on over 5 columns. Here is my css.

```
    .cal-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.cal-quarter-hour {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ddd;
    height: 100%;
}

.cal-half-hour {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #bbb;
    height: 100%;
}

.cal-hour {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    height: 100%;
}

.cal-border-right {
    border-right: 0.5px solid #ccc;
    height: 100%;
}

.cal-today {
    background-color: #ffffcc;

}
```

I have looked at other solutions and a number of tutorials on this but at the moment I get one long column. which does not move to the next column.

How do I make the divs populate down to, say, the 12th row and then start in the next column and then the next given the correct number of divs?

Simon

Answer (score 0):

`grid-template-rows` expects you to define each and every row of the grid. When you defined `grid-template-rows: 14px`, that means your grid will have "one row with 14px height".

You should set `grid-template-rows` to `repeat(12, 14px)` which is the same as writing `14px` 12 times.

You didn't give the whole code, but I think you'll also have to set the `height` of those smaller divs to `25%`

I've setup an example with only 3 rows per column (so the code doesn't come out huge)

```css
 .calendar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 60px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 14px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px dashed lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```